# How to load test dynamically using unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have not grew up to use test frameworks yet. But sometimes I want to check all tests. When I work on a test I use one only. Help me load modules/Tests dynamically. I guess I've missed something a little.

```
import sys
import importlib
import settings
settings.TESTING = True
settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'

from application import app
import unittest

argv = sys.argv[1:]
ALL = argv[0] == 'ALL'

tests = dict(
  RestAuthTestCase=('ext.core.test.lib.rest_auth', 'RestAuthTestCase'),
  UserModelTestCase=('ext.user.test.user_model', 'UserModelTestCase'),
  BudgetModelTestCase=('ext.budget.test.budget_model', 'BudgetModelTestCase'),
  TagModelTestCase=('ext.budget.test.tag_model', 'TagModelTestCase'),
  ExpenseModelTestCase=('ext.budget.test.expense_model', 'ExpenseModelTestCase'),
  TableTestCase=('ext.budget.test.table', 'TableTestCase'),
  UserRestTestCase=('ext.user.test.rest', 'UserRestTestCase')
)

for test_key in argv:
  test_pkg, test_name = tests[test_key]
  mod = __import__(test_pkg, globals(), locals(), fromlist=[test_name])
  klass = getattr(mod, test_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Comment: I see I should read the documentation better. Standard features are enough. Look https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-options

Comment: Have you considered using a unit test framework?